# What's the difference between (new { htmlAtributes = new { }) and (new { })

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I know they are anonymous types but I don't get that Razor syntax. In some documentation I found an example like this:

`@Html.Label("Hello", new { htmlAtributes = new { id = "hi" }})`

In most cases I just use this simple: `@Html.Label("Hello", new { id = "hi" })`

Help me to understand this, and I don't know why my `document.getElementById('hi').innerHTML = "changed";` doesn't work with the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first way use for `Html.LabelFor`

```
@Html.LabelFor(c=>c.Email, new { htmlAtributes = new { id = "hi" } })
```

If you use `@Html.Label("Hello", new { htmlAtributes = new { id = "hi" }})`

it will generate to (with htmlatributes is an attribute of label tag)

```
<label for="Hello" htmlatributes="{ id = hi }">Hello</label>
```

You need use second way

```
@Html.Label("Hello", new { id = "hi" })
```

Comment: I got you. But what if I want to use the first way, how could I access to its data from Javascript? I tried: `document.getElementById('hi').innerHTML = "changed";` and doesn't even have effect on it.

Comment: you can use document.getElementsByTagName("label")[index]

Comment: I typed `htmlAtributes` instead of `htmlAttributes`, that's why It wasn't working.